# Equivalency of feedforward and recurrent neural network

Tags: neural-networks

I'm involved in solving a problem as described below and wondering if you could kindly help me figure it out:
"approximating a single input single output  single layer with two neurons , recurrent neural network (neurons have feedback just to themselves) with a feedforward network"
How could I do this and is there any useful source in this regard?
thanks in advance for your time.

best regards

Comment: I mean, you just need to remove from the preactivation of the hidden layer the $Wh^{t-1}$ part no?